# How to sort questions on Stack Overflow by number of views?

Tags: support, views, question-lists

How can one sort questions by number of views? I'd find this useful.

Views and votes are sometimes very different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't any built-in feature to view questions sorted by views.

But you can use [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60366/most-viewed-questions).

Comment: @ColonelPanic The data explorer is quite handy and this probably is the best (and possibly is the only) way for you to achieve this. However, you should be aware that if a question doesn't appear, it may be because it's too new--the Data Explorer doesn't cover SE in real-time; it uses snapshots instead. According to [its FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq), the snapshots are taken monthly.